# Makefile for C program that uses numpy extensions

Tags: python, c, include, numpy, makefile

Please what is the simplest / most elegant way of how to determine correct paths for numpy include as they are present on target system ? And then use it by make command ? At the moment I am using

gcc ... -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/

and I would like to have those two includes automatically selected based on system on which the build is perfromed on.

It seems like I can get the second include like this:

```
python -c "import numpy; print numpy.__path__[0] + 'core/include/numpy/'"
```

but I am not sure about the first one and even if I was I still wouldn't be sure how to best use it from makefile (in an easy / elegant way)

Answer (score 3):

`numpy.get_include()` is the easiest/best way to get the includes.  If your C extension module uses numpy then in [Extension](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) you have to use `include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]`.   Why `numpy.get_include()` doesn't seem to have any documentation I don't know.

Then you can do as user1056255 suggests but just a bit better...

```
CFLAGS = $(shell python-config --includes) $(shell python -c "import numpy; print '-I' + numpy.get_include()")
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some googling and experimentig this is what I came up with:

```
CFLAGS = $(shell python-config --includes) $(shell python -c "import numpy; print '-I' + numpy.__path__[0] + '/core/include/numpy/'")
```

Not sure how reliable it is but it seems to be working on all machines so far.

I had to use $(shell ...) for setting up make variables from shell output as method proposed by mux didn't work for me